# Restkit load objects to an existing object

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm using Restkit 0.22 with Core data, this is my schema:

```
----------           --------
| itemA  |           | itemB |
----------           ---------
| itemsB | 1 --- > N | itemA |
----------           ---------
```

this is one to many relationship.
I load all the itemA items from local JSON file.

and i want to make a call to my web service and get itemB items and the result of each call I want to add to a specific existing itemA.

in the response of itemB items there is not id or foreign key that indicates that those items belong to the specific item that I want to add them to.

how can i achieve/map it?

Comment: What URL do you use to get the `ItemB` objects for a specified `ItemA` instance?

Comment: it's a web service, there is no specific value of itemA that i'm sending. i just want to start an operation and to connect the result items to itemA

Comment: So you are requesting for a specific `ItemA`, or all at the same time? How do you know which `ItemB` connects to which `ItemA`?

Comment: i build the url request according to the itemA property called URLPath. each itemA has its own url paths so that my request look likes this. www.mywebservice.com?url=[somevalue].com

Comment: So your URL has a query parameter which is a URL, but not an identifier for any `ItemA` - then you have (at least an efficiency) problem - can you change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the current information, RestKit can't help you as there is no easily accessible identification information (the URL query parameter can't be easily accessed).

So, your main option currently is to simply iterate the mapping result contents and associate the results with the `itemA` object that you used to make the request manually and then save the context.

Comment: i seems that i have to change some things on my web service to make it work like i want to. thanks!

Comment: @Wain could you possibly explain how this works _with_ accessible identification information?

Comment: Never mind, answered my own question. Had to change the assignmentPolicy to RKUnionAssignmentPolicy on my RKRelationshipMapping.